# filter objects in two seperate subject foreach if

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I have a question. I am trying to filter a match game.
In the match game I want to filter the players ...but because there is a home and away team ....I want to seperate them. How is this possible.

my structure

```
Name    Type
Id  string
MatchNumber int
Date    string
Time    string
ClockDirection  string
TrueStartTime   string
TrueEndTime string
DepartmentId    string
DepartmentCode  string
DepartmentName  string
HomeTeamId  string
HomeClubId  string
HomeTeam    string
AwayTeamId  string
AwayClubId  string
AwayTeam    string
PoolId  string
PoolName    string
ResultHome  int
ResultGuest int
PeriodStandings MatchReportPeriodStandingsItem[]
Actions MatchReportActionsItem[]
Players MatchReportPlayersItem[]
Coaches MatchReportCoachesItem[]
Referees    MatchReportRefereesItem[]
Officials   MatchReportOfficialsItem[]
```

for the players info it's like this

```
MatchReportPlayersItem

Properties

Name    Type
Id  string
Cap string
Name    string
Captain boolean
Team    string
```

If I want to show a list of players It's like this

```
$Players = [];
                    foreach($Match->Players as $playerItem) {
                    $Players[] = $playerItem->Name . ' ' . $playerItem->Team;
                }
```

resulting in

```
De Craemer H, Van Der Linden H, Baeckelandt H, Christiaens H, Degryse H, Devos H, Dumoulin H, Gevaert H, Gheysen H, Louage H, Mestdag H, Monballieu H, Peremans H, Stieperaere H, Van Den Berghe H, Van Hoestenberghe H, Verschelde H, Verschelde H, Bekar G, Benabdelouahed G, Bochet G, Bourgeois G, Brahim G, Brismee G, Brismee G, Broutard G, Carin G
```

where the H and G ...stands for Home and Guest ....I want it in two separate list/table ...how am I gonna accomplish this.

So far I got this.

```
$Players = [];
                    foreach($Match->Players as $playerItem) {
                    $Players[] = $playerItem->Name . ' ' . $playerItem->Team;
                } 
         if ($playerItem->Team == "G"){
        echo implode(', ', $Players); } 
        else {
    echo " ";
}
```

can someone help me on this subject thanx!

Comment: How is the structure of your Players array. Write your complete for each, the code you provided is missing some characters.

Comment: That's some creative indentation.

Comment: Please share your input array+completer foreach code+what outcome coming from your code+what desired output you want?

Comment: I have edited my question ....maybe this will show some light on the subject...if I got it totally wrong or it is some silly question ...I am sorry for that...but I am still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<?php

class Match {

    public $Players;

    public function __construct($players) {
        $this->Players = $players;
    }

}

class Player {

    public $Name;
    public $Team;

    public function __construct($name, $team) {
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Team = $team;
    }

}

$Match = new Match(
        array(
            new Player("John", "Gremio"),
            new Player("Mike", "Gremio"),
            new Player("Tom", "Inter"),
            new Player("Silva", "Inter")
        )
    );

$Players = [];
foreach ($Match->Players as $playerItem) {
    $Players[$playerItem->Team][] = $playerItem->Name;
}

var_dump($Players);
```

This output:

```
array(2) {
  'Gremio' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "John"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "Mike"
  }
  'Inter' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "Tom"
    [1] =>
    string(5) "Silva"
  }
}
```

EDITED (new solution):

```
<?php

class Match {

    public $Players;

    public function __construct($players) {
        $this->Players = $players;
    }

}

class Player {

    public $Name;
    public $Team;

    public function __construct($name, $team) {
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Team = $team;
    }

}

function getPlayersFromTeam($team, $players) {
    $Players = array();
    foreach ($players as $playerItem) {
        if ($playerItem->Team == $team) {
            $Players[$playerItem->Team][] = $playerItem->Name;
        }
    }
    return $Players;
}

$Match = new Match(
        array(
    new Player("John", "Gremio"),
    new Player("Mike", "Gremio"),
    new Player("Tom", "Inter"),
    new Player("Silva", "Inter")
        )
);

var_dump(getPlayersFromTeam("Gremio", $Match->Players));
var_dump(getPlayersFromTeam("Inter", $Match->Players));
```

Comment: Look the new solution, it helps?

Comment: thx! it worked ...but var_dump ...show me also a lot of info that I don't need...how am i suppose to echo this out?

Comment: Should I use a $_GET function?

Comment: var_dump is a PHP command to display the content of a variable. You should use the function directly. If my answer solve your problem, please mark It as answered!